# Lost keybindings on Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I´m trying to change the scheme for key bindings on Visual Studio for Mac, but it seems that in the update from 2017 to 2019 I lost the other options.

The only option I have is the one shown below (I don´t have other options)

[image: Visual Studio Key Bindings]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is the app recognizing the user as being the one who initially setup up the bindings?

Comment: You could try copying the key binding file from 7.0 over to 8.0. There should be an .xml file in `~/Library/VisualStudio/7.0/KeyBindings/`. Exit VS Mac and try copying that file over to `~/Library/VisualStudio/8.0/KeyBindings/`. I do not believe the xml file format has changed for key bindings.

Comment: Thanks @MattWard it worked partially, I removed the Visual Studio Windows KeyBindings by deleting Custom.mac-kb.xml on that folders but left with Visual Studio (for Mac) default KeyBinding, what I wanted was to have the options shown in the documentation, but temporary this default keybindings work for me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/customizing-the-ide?view=vsmac-2019#key-bindings